# Deleting multiple users with Ansible ad-hoc command

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

When running Ansible ad-hoc to remove users I was unable to feed multiple items to 
module. Like this:

```
ansible -i my_inv all -m user -a"name={{ users }} state=absent" --check --extra-vars='{"users":["user1","user2"]}'
```

the output is:

```
    server1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "name": "['user1', 'user2']",
    "state": "absent"
     }
```

it seems to be not opening array correctly.
Making json file also didnt work.

```
    {
   "users":["user1","user2"]
    }
```

Is there any way to do it without writing a role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`name` parameter of `user` module takes a string as an argument, not a list.

You need either to loop (and for that you'd need a play - not necessarily a role), or run `ansible` executable several times.